# Изменить порт Apache на другой

Tags: ubuntu, apache

У меня Apache стоит на порту 80. Хочу поменять, например, на 8080.

Менял здесь: `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` - не помогает. После перезапуска Apache порт восстанавливается на 80. В других местах менял - тоже самое.

Как изменить порт?

*ports.conf*:

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/PQvfCB6i

Comment: Замены в ports.conf вполне достаточно. Порт может остаться старым, потому что не срабатывает перезагрузка. Попробуйте убить остановить апач, проверить командов ps, что не осталось процессов с именем apache2. Если процессы остались - убейти их вручную. После этого стартуйте апач снова.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apache2.conf `Listen 8080` попробуйте
а еще грепните все по слову Listen в /etc/init.d/apache2

Comment: В каком месте поставить Listen 8080?

Comment: в принципе в любоом, только чтобы был вне xml-тегов, так же можете настроить виртуальный хост на отдельный порт, правила использования такие же.

Comment: Выдаёт: "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server"

Comment: Заработало сразу на 2-х портах ))) А как теперь убрать порт 80 полностью?

Comment: насчет forbidden у вас не настроены права, назначте пользователя из группы www-data, и измените флаги привелегий на доступ к чтению, ну а если на двух портах грепайте find / -name "*" -type f -exec grep -l "Listen 80" {} \; и в тех файлах что будут результате заменяйте на нужный порт. хотя врядли апач должен слушать 80 пор уже если вы внесли изменения в apache2.conf

Comment: Forbidden уже работает, как теперь отключить 80-ый порт?

Comment: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Это что значит? ))) Почти победили... На 80-ом порту должен сидеть другой демон, я его запустил и занял 80-ый порт... Сейчас если я запускаю апач, он ругается, что не может встать на порт 80

Comment: Еще раз говорю, выполните ту команду. И еще убедитесь, что все найденные файлы принадлежат apache, и файл находится по пути /etc/int.d/apache2/apache2.conf если что, так же проверьте httpd.conf возможно также директива есть в файле etc/int.d/apache2/sites-available/default и закоментите Listen в ports.conf

Comment: Убрал 80-ый порт из /etc/apache2/ports.conf - всё заработало как надо! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
    Listen 8080
    
    <IfModule ssl_module>
            Listen 443
    </IfModule>
    
    <IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
            Listen 443
    </IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 8080
</IfModule>
```

После этого **systemctl reload apache2**